# How to adjust data table column width

Tags: jquery, css, datatables

I am trying to set datatable column width. Please see the code below.

```
$('#datatable5').DataTable({
        "order" : [ [ 0, "desc" ] ],
        "columnDefs": [ { "width": "100px", "target":0 }, { "width": "400px", "target":1  }, { "width": "200px", "target":2  } ,{ "width": "200px", "target":3  } ,{ "width": "200px", "target":4  } ,{ "width": "200px", "target":5   } ,{ "width": "200px", "target":6  }, { "width": "200px" , "target":7 }, { "width": "200px", "target":8  }, { "width": "200px", "target":9  }],
        //"sPaginationType" : "bs_two_button",
        //"iDisplayLength" : 9,
        "scrollX": true,
        // "sScrollX" : "100%",
         "paging": true,
         "sPaginationType" : "bs_two_button",
         "info" : false,

        "fnDrawCallback" : function(oSettings) {
            $('td').removeClass('sorting_1');
        }
});
```

How to passe column width explicitly to datatables? I tried the css to set width for the table. However, it was not success?

Answer (score 1):

Try using 'targets' in columnDefs, not 'target', even if you are only giving it a single column.

If you want to do it via CSS, then you can give each column it's own class (using className in columnDefs), and use that to set the width.